# Can I make Google auto-focus the search field faster?

Tags: google, user-interface

It used to be instant but it seems to take longer and longer to actually load the page to a point where the browser is ready to focus the search field so I can actually search.

Can I work around this?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Your options will depend on that fact.

Answer (score 1):

To work around, you could probably use a plugin/extension to immediately do a Google search without having to load the google.com home page.  If you are using Google Chrome, then you can just type your search into the address bar ("omnibar").

Answer (score 1):

After you entered the URL google.com and pressed *ENTER* you can start typing right away. No need to wait on any focus. Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari tested.

Comment: Maybe your internet connection and PC speed will affect the outcome.